# FCM Push notifications do not work on iOS 11

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, ios11

I use Firebase as a backend. I also use FCM as one of the provided features from Firebase. FCM worked well in iOS 10, but after switching to iOS 11, push notifications stopped coming to user devices, and I myself did not receive any push notifications sent from the cloud functions or the Notification section in the Firebase Console. How to fix this problem?

**Update:** I sent several push notifications from Firebase Notifcations, but they do not come.

```
// MARK: - Push notification

extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func registerPushNotification(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })

        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        //When the notifications of this code worked well, there was not yet.
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }

    // [START receive_message]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            debugPrint("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        debugPrint(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        debugPrint(userInfo)

        completionHandler(.newData)
    }

    // showing push notification

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        if let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as? [String : Any] {
            let routerManager = RouterManager()
            routerManager.launchRouting(userInfo)
        }
        completionHandler()
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        if let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo as? [String : Any] {
            if let categoryID = userInfo["categoryID"] as? String {
                if categoryID == RouterManager.Categories.newMessage.id {
                    if let currentConversation = ChatGeneralManager.shared.currentChatPersonalConversation, let dataID = userInfo["dataID"] as? String  {
                        // dataID is conversationd id for newMessage
                        if currentConversation.id == dataID {
                            completionHandler([])
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if let badge = notification.request.content.badge {
                AppBadgesManager.shared.pushNotificationHandler(userInfo, pushNotificationBadgeNumber: badge.intValue)
            }
        }
        completionHandler([.alert,.sound, .badge])
    }

}

// [START ios_10_data_message_handling]
extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        let pushNotificationManager = PushNotificationManager()
        pushNotificationManager.saveNotificationTokenInDatabase(token: fcmToken, success: nil, fail: nil)
    }


    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the foreground.
    func application(received remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        debugPrint(remoteMessage.appData)
    }

}
```

Comment: Could the code above be updated?

Comment: @NCT127 do you mean update to Swift 5? I do not have access to this code already

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It appears that with FirebaseInstanceID 2.0.3 push notifications don't work. It helped me to set: pod 'FirebaseInstanceID', "2.0.0".
Maybe in next version this will be fixed.

Comment: I solved this putting **pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '2.0.0'**

Comment: Yes, there is a bug in FirebaseInstanceID 2.0.1–2.0.3 which is fixed in the next release of Firebase. The two workarounds are to (a) Always call `application.registerForRemoteNotifications()` on app start, or (b) temporarily lock to FirebaseInstanceID 2.0.0.

Comment: FYI, we released `FirebaseInstanceID 2.0.4` today, which should resolve the issues you're seeing. Please update to that if you were having trouble with 2.0.1–2.0.3. Thanks!

Comment: Locking the FirebaseInstanceID pod worked for me, always calling application.registerForRemoteNotifications() on app start didn't work for me at all.

Comment: `Using FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.6)` and receiving the notification response as a success but still no notification shown on ios `11.1.1`...  `application.registerForRemoteNotifications()` is also present.  Is there a real solution for this?

Answer (score 7):

Please update your FCM pod

```
pod ‘Firebase/Messaging’
```

to the latest version, which is 2.0.6

```
Installing FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.6)
Installing FirebaseMessaging (2.0.6)
```

It should work with iOS 11+ devices.

Answer (score 3):

this work to me .
IOS 11 , SWIFT 4.
take from : https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-remote-notification-with-firebase-tutorial-118acd3ebce1

PODS
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Crash'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
pod 'Firebase/Invites'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging' 
pod 'Firebase/Performance'
pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'FirebaseInstanceID'

```html
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  MiprimerFirbaseIOS
//
//  Created by JUAN on 7/01/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 net.juanfrancisco.blog. All Free.
//

import UIKit
import CoreData
import UserNotifications

import Firebase



@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    // iOS10+, called when presenting notification in foreground
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        NSLog("[UserNotificationCenter] applicationState: \(applicationStateString) willPresentNotification: \(userInfo)")
        //TODO: Handle foreground notification
        completionHandler([.alert])
    }

    // iOS10+, called when received response (default open, dismiss or custom action) for a notification
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        NSLog("[UserNotificationCenter] applicationState: \(applicationStateString) didReceiveResponse: \(userInfo)")
        //TODO: Handle background notification
        completionHandler()
    }
}

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        NSLog("[RemoteNotification] didRefreshRegistrationToken: \(fcmToken)")
    }

    // iOS9, called when presenting notification in foreground
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        NSLog("[RemoteNotification] applicationState: \(applicationStateString) didReceiveRemoteNotification for iOS9: \(userInfo)")
        if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
            //TODO: Handle foreground notification
        } else {
            //TODO: Handle background notification
        }
    }
}


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

     static var shared: AppDelegate { return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate }

    var applicationStateString: String {
        if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
            return "active"
        } else if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background {
            return "background"
        }else {
            return "inactive"
        }
    }

    func requestNotificationAuthorization(application: UIApplication) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        requestNotificationAuthorization(application: application)
        if let userInfo = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] {
            NSLog("[RemoteNotification] applicationState: \(applicationStateString) didFinishLaunchingWithOptions for iOS9: \(userInfo)")
            //TODO: Handle background notification
        }


        
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
        self.saveContext()
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        /*
         The persistent container for the application. This implementation
         creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
         application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
         error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        */
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MiprimerFirbaseIOS")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                 
                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me! Thanks for this, i was struggling with the iOS side of things :)

Comment: Where do I save the token to use in the backend?

Answer (score 2):

I read this [topic](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/254) and added this code `application.registerForRemoteNotifications()` to the AppDelegate method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and it worked, but unfortunately current users will not receive notifications until they are updated to the new version. Please see https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/327#issuecomment-331782299

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue with Firebase SDK where push notifications stop working after app relaunch or when killed. A work around for this was suggested:

```
let deleteCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "oneTimeWorkaroundKey")
        if deleteCount == 0 {
            InstanceID.instanceID().deleteID { error in
                if let cError = error {
                    log("APNS: Error on delete: \(cError)")
                } else {
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(deleteCount + 1, forKey: "oneTimeWorkaroundKey")
                }
            }
        }
```

Heres a link to see the discussions held about this, one case is still open trying to resolve this issue https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2438