# Xamarin's implementation of FCM update broke data messages on iOS 11 and Xamarin

Tags: firebase, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, ios11

I updated my project's Firebase packages, including Cloud Messaging, with 2.0.0 release. Now I see that iOS 11 devices do not receive data messages from FCM. Unlike [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391818/fcm-push-notifications-do-not-work-on-ios-11) thread, I have no problems receiving notifications via APNs with Firebase.

I implemented every necessary change, including replacing the old `Messaging.SharedInstance.Connect()` method with `Messaging.SharedInstance.ShouldEstablishDirectChannel = true;`.

I have tried to implement the `IMessagingDelegate`'s methods `ApplicationReceivedRemoteMessage` and `DidReceiveMessage` - both separately and together. neither hits breakpoints.

The Xamarin guys have not updated the guideline [here](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/firebaseioscloudmessaging) as of this question's writing. Has anyone else encountered this issue? What can be done?

Comment: Did you got any luck on this ?