# Cannot receive Custom notification in iOS using Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-notifications

I'm developing an iOS app that uses `Firebase push notifications`. It worked well with Testing Firebase Notifications and receiving notification on `iOS device`.
But Custom notification is not receiving on the device. How to debug what is a problem ? Is it a problem from Firebase console or iOS development issue. 
Using an iPhone with ios 11.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391818/fcm-push-notifications-do-not-work-on-ios-11

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, FCM isn't working on iOS 11. Read about it here
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/327

In your podfile change your **FirebaseMessaging** to `pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '2.0.0'`

Comment: I have check the latest version, FirebaseMessaging is 2.0.6 .

Comment: What I meant was I had a similar issue recently, when I set the pod back to 2.0.0 it worked.