# How to temporarily lock to FirebaseInstanceID 2.0.0

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been facing issues in sending push notification to IOS clients who are running in IOS 11, on surfing the internet found that temporarily lock to FirebaseInstanceID 2.0.0 in the pod file.But if i do that i am getting the error message as follows,

```
**Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseInstanceID":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    FirebaseInstanceID (= 2.0.10)
  In Podfile:
    FirebaseInstanceID (= 2.0.0)
Specs satisfying the `FirebaseInstanceID (= 2.0.0), FirebaseInstanceID (= 2.0.10)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `10.2` on target `PushNotificationDemo` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.**
```

[FCM Push notifications do not work on iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391818/fcm-push-notifications-do-not-work-on-ios-11/46428026#46428026)

Is there any other way of enabling push notifications in IOS 11.Thanks in advance

My Pod file as below,

## Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

## platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'PushNotificationDemo' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

# Pods for PushNotificationDemo
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  #pod 'FirebaseInstanceID', '2.0.0'

target 'PushNotificationDemoTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

target 'PushNotificationDemoUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end

Comment: Did u set this :  FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled = YES

Comment: yes, I have enabled  FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled = YES yet i am not receiving any notification @https://stackoverflow.com/users/6600624/shivam-tripathi

Comment: Share your Podfile. Likely you have something else in it that is requiring  a later version.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/556617/paul-beusterien i have shared my pod file