# Firebase Push notifications not working ios11 swift 4.1

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, cocoapods

After updating my CellPhone and reinstalling the app, i got noticed that the push notifications were going through `remoteMessage` methods and not by the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` methods.
After updating the firebase, the framework called `nanopb` dissapeared and when i try to build the project, i'm facing the 
`ld: framework not found nanopb 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`
I tried to set the pods like this:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core', '4.0.3'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '4.0.3'
pod 'FirebaseInstanceID', '2.0.0'
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391818/fcm-push-notifications-do-not-work-on-ios-11) i tried to, but it is presented the same "not found" error.

I also have the notifications capability activated:
[image]
[image]

My code in the appDelegate is:

```
let gcmMessageIDKey         = "gcm.message_id"

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    }else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification), name: .InstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)



    if let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken{
        print("FCM token: \(token)")
    } else {
        //will refresh in some method for later
    }
    return true
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

}
```

There is a way to add the nanopb framework to my project or whats the necessary steps to workaround this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I opened my app today and it worked again...

Apparently it was a problem with the firebase... All my other apps didn't get any push notification for the whole day.

Comment: For Firebase 4.0.3+ the nanopod framework is not used and then it is deleted.

Comment: I have the same problem now. Push notifications were working earlier and can't get them working today! Seriously I don't understand what's wrong!!