# FCM Notification is not coming in iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to show only default UI notification in my app with FCM, Apple Push Notification is working fine in all iOS version, but in iOS 12 I did not get Notification.

Will anybody help me to show default UI notification in iOS 12. What change i have to make in code or .plist?

Comment: Have you tried to downgrade Firebase SDK version in iOS ? Which one are you using ? I found a similar case here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391818/fcm-push-notifications-do-not-work-on-ios-11.

Comment: @NeverHopeless Previously i was used Firebase SDk version 3, and i updated SDK today and i got the same problem in iOS 12. Notification is working fine in iOS 10 and 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check that you get the device token in your app delegate or not if you does not receive the device token you should change the APNS Token type to one of them and then sync with your configuration:

```
FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .sandbox)
```

or

```
FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .none)
```

or

```
FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .prod)
```

Comment: i got the device token for both APNS and FCM, When i check my notification via pushtry.com i recieved the FCM message, but my APN methods not called. This is happing in iOS 12 only, i get notification properly in all version of iOS < 12.

Comment: //use this method To receive notifications for iOS 11 and below
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {your code here}
//

#if defined(__IPHONE_12_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_12_0
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {your code here}
#endif

Comment: I am using these all functions (Swift). but these methods is not call.

Comment: I'm not sure that you use the #if condition or not...because if you don't use it the methods never called